# Problem numbering exsheets questions in appendix

Tags: numbering, exsheets

I would like to include exercises in an appendix of a book and I have a problem to obtain correct numbers for these exercises:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = chapter ,
  counter-format = ch.se.qu
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}
\section{foo one}
\begin{question}
  foo one
\end{question}

\appendix
\chapter{bar}
\section{bar one}
\begin{question}
  bar one
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

For section **1** in Appendix **A**, I would expect a number of **A.1.1** for the first question in that section. However, I get **1.1.1** which is the correct number for the first chapter *outside* the appendix. Accordingly, numbers are as **2.1.1** for Appendix **B** etc.

[image]

What do I need to do to obtain the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another `\SetupExSheets` command after `\appendix` with `counter-format=ch[A].se.qu` to enable uppercase numbers for the chapter counter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = chapter ,
  counter-format = ch.se.qu
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}
\section{foo one}
\begin{question}
  foo one
\end{question}

\appendix

\SetupExSheets{
  counter-format = ch[A].se.qu
}

\chapter{bar}
\section{bar one}
\begin{question}
  bar one
\end{question}


\chapter{Another one}
\section{Foo}
\begin{question}
  bar one
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With an up to date `exsheets` the following suffices for the whole document: `counter-format = \thesection.qu`.

Comment: @clemens Thanks for the hint! It works great with the 0.20 `exsheets` version! I noticed that there is also a `counter-format = \thechapter.qu` option to get the `ch.qu` version right with appendices.